# i am building my keras transfer learning model like shown below One thing i am unable to do is set training=False for batchNorm layers in xception

Tags: tensorflow, keras, transfer-learning, batch-normalization

As it you can see I dont wanna change the way I built this model there is a way to change but that converts xception model into some functional model and In model summary it just shows Xception instead of all its layers and also I cant apply grad cam. So please help someone.

**code**

```
def build_model():
    # use imagenet - pre-trainined weights for images
    baseModel =Xception(weights= 'imagenet', include_top = False, input_shape=(224, 224, 3))
    for layer in baseModel.layers:
      layer.trainable = False
      bn_layer.trainable=False
   
    headModel =baseModel.output 
    headModel = Flatten()(headModel)
    headModel = Dense(64,activation="LeakyReLU")(headModel)
    headModel = Dropout(0.5)(headModel)
    headModel = Dense(32,activation="LeakyReLU")(headModel)
    headModel = Dropout(0.4)(headModel)
    headModel = Dense(16, activation="LeakyReLU")(headModel)
    headModel = Dropout(0.3)(headModel)
    headModel = Dense(8, activation="LeakyReLU")(headModel)
    headModel = Dropout(0.2)(headModel)
    headModel = Dense(3, activation="softmax")(headModel)
    
    x = Model(baseModel.inputs,outputs=headModel)

    optimizers = Adam(learning_rate=  0.001)
    x.compile(loss = 'categorical_crossentropy', optimizer = optimizers, metrics = ['accuracy'])
    return x

x= build_model()
sum=x.summary()
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understood is that you want to freeze all the layer in the base model, right? You can do the following:

```
    for layer in baseModel.layers:
            layer.trainable = False
```

In this case, your code is right, except that you do not need the second line.

Instead if you want to train all the layers but the BatchNormalization layers then you can do the following:

```
    for layer in model.layers:
            if not isinstance(layer, layers.BatchNormalization):
                    layer.trainable = True
```

For more read: https://keras.io/guides/transfer_learning/ Especially, the section **Example: the BatchNormalization layer.**